# Split number string arbitrarily using bash into fixed number of variables

Tags: bash

I have a string with 3000 elements (NOT in series) in bash,

```
sections='1 2 4 ... 3000'
```

I am trying to split this string into x chunks of length n.
I want x to be typically between 3-10. Each chunk may not be of
the same length.

Each chunk is the input to a job.

Looking at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/122499/bash-split-a-list-of-files
and using bash arrays, my first attempt looks like this:

```
#! /bin/bash

nArgs=10
nChunkSize=10

z="0 1 2 .. 1--"

zs=(${z// / })
echo ${zs[@]}

for i in $nArgs; do
  echo "Creating argument: "$i
  startItem=$i*$nChunkSize
  zArg[$i] = ${zs[@]:($startItem:$chunkSize}
done

echo "Resulting args"

for i in $nArgs; do
 echo "Argument"${zArgs[$1]}
done
```

The above is far from working I'm afraid. Any pointers on the ${zs[@]:($startItem:$chunkSize} syntax?

For an input of 13 elements:

`z='0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 10 11 12 15'`

nChunks=3
and nArgs=4
I would like to obtain an array with 3 elements, zs with content

```
zs[0] = '0 1 2 3'
zs[1] = '4 5 6 7'
zs[2] = '8 10 11 12 15'
```

Each zs will be used as arguments to subsequent jobs.

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: Use shellcheck.net to identify and correct the more glaring errors.

Answer (score 2):

First note: *This is a bad idea*. It won't work reliably with arbitrary (non-numeric) contents, as bash doesn't have support for nested arrays.

---

```
output=( )

sections_str='1 2 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 3000'
batch_size=4
read -r -a sections <<<"$sections_str"
for ((i=0; i<${#sections[@]}; i+=batch_size)); do
  current_pieces=( "${sections[@]:i:batch_size}" )
  output+=( "${current_pieces[*]}" )
done

declare -p output # to view your output
```

Notes:

- `zs=( $z )` is buggy. For example, any `*` inside your list will be replaced with a list of filenames in the current directory. Use `read -a` to read into an array in a reliable way that doesn't depend on shell configuration other than IFS (which can be controlled scoped to just that one line with `IFS=' ' read -r -a`).
- `${array[@]:start:count}` expands to up to `count` items from your array, starting at position `start`.

Comment: This seem to do it for me! I will not have any non-numeric content. Thanks!!